# How do I get ignored style properties in js?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am doing some work on a CSS/JS plugin. I want to be able to write something like this in my stylesheet:

```
.whatever {
  background: 
    -custom-renderer("ctx.beginPath(); ctx.moveTo(0, 40); ctx.lineTo(240, 40); ctx.moveTo(260, 40); ctx.lineTo(500, 40); ctx.moveTo(495, 35); ctx.lineTo(500, 40); ctx.lineTo(495, 45);")
    repeat-x;
  background: rgb(30, 30, 30); /* fallback */
```

I would need to access this property with Javascript and rewrite it with a different property. Now the problem is that all of the methods I know of (`document.styleSheets[1].cssRules`, `document.defaultView.getMatchedCSSRules`, etc.) tend to show only the fallback property (which is normally great behavior).

Comment: Not sure if there is a way other than using something like JQuery to get the data from the file, but that requires parsing it the hard way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401668/how-can-i-get-css-comments-with-javascript

Comment: I was afraid so and it sort of makes the cost/benefit equation of what I was planing not practical :(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you append the modified CSS rules as a "`<style>`" element into the document head..

Take a look on that..

http://jonraasch.com/blog/javascript-style-node

*you can set an ID on the "`<style>`" element to easily modify it with javascript

Comment: The question is about how to access the current (ignored) style, not how to set a new one.