# Returning metadata with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, metadata

I have a CSS stylesheet that's dynamically created on the server, and returned via a `<link>` tag. Is it possible to return any metadata with this stylesheet, that I could read with JavaScript?

(The use case: the stylesheet I return is a combination of several smaller ones. I want my JavaScript code to be able to detect which smaller ones were included.)

I considered adding some custom properties to an element:

```
body {
  -my-custom-prop1:0;
  -my-custom-prop2:0;
}
```

But when I try to read these with:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body)['-my-custom-prop1']
```

they're not returned. Any other ideaas?

**EDIT:** I ended up taking a slightly different approach. Instead of adding a `<link>` tag, I made an AJAX request to get the stylesheet, and added its text to a `<style>` tag. This way I could use the HTTP response headers to include metadata. Of course, this won't work across domains, like a `<link>` tag does.

Comment: Which browsers? (including version and OS)

Comment: I'd like to be able to read the metadata with all modern browsers, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**See example of the following →**](http://jsfiddle.net/fXp5v/2/)

Though I think this technique is ill-advised, here's something I developed that I've tested to work in Chrome, FF, Safari and IE8.

First, I picked the `list-style-image` property to be used to store the meta data since it can contain any string in the `url()` parameter and yet wasn't going to be used under any normal circumstances in the body CSS.

Then I implemented a common cross-browser function to `getComputedStyle` since this isn't available in all browsers.

Then I parsed the return property to get only the data within the `url('')`, resulting in these functions:

```
var getStyle = function(el, cssprop) {
    if (el.currentStyle) {
        return el.currentStyle[cssprop];
    } else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
        return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "")[cssprop];
    } else {
        return (el.style) ? el.style[cssprop] : 0;
    }
};

var pullCSSMeta = function() {
    var aMeta = getStyle(document.body, 'listStyleImage').split('/'),
        meta = aMeta[aMeta.length - 1];

    return decodeURIComponent(meta.substr(0, meta.length - 1).replace(/"$/,''));
};
```

If you need to store more than one piece of information you could comma-delineate the data or potentially even store a JSON string.  I hope you have a good reason for wanting to do this as I think there are better ways to store meta data... but there you go!

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/fXp5v/2/)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by ill-advised. This is awesome. The only thing about this is that I can find is the performance hit of generating a 404 every time the file is loaded.

Comment: That's true, I forgot to mention that part, thanks.  It just feels very hacky to do something like this, but it's fun to know that you can.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it's the closest to what I asked for. But I ended up taking a different approach; see my edit to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

The returned object actually represents the CSS 2.1 used values, not the computed values. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

You might be able to interrogate these styles via another method though:
http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript

Answer (score 1):

I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114272/how-do-i-get-ignored-style-properties-in-js) a while ago. It turns out that you have to parse the stylesheet text manually with javascript. I decided it was not worth the bother and found a different solution to my problem. You could use some clever tricks like standard properties on bogus classes would work I guess.

Comment: Were you able to access the text though? I tried linkEle.innerText, but it returns an empty string (at least in Chrome).